# Send handlebars data to client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am building a node.js application and I'm using handlebars. I wanted to check if there's a way for me to send data defined in a handlebars template to client side javascript to be used in calculations. For example, here is my controller:

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {

    var projectId = req.params.id;
    var context = {
        cost: 500,
        revenue: 1000, 
    }

    res.render('../views/reports', context)
};
```

On the client-side javascript file, I want to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(context) {
    var profit = context.revenue - context.cost;
});
```

I'm not sure how to pass the context into the client side javascript.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Client**

```
$.post("/endpoint_on_server",
{
    id: "xyz"
},
function(context){ //the result of the res.render
    //update the view
    $('body').html(context);
});
```

**Server**

```
app.post('/endpoint_on_server', function(req, res){
  var projectId = req.params.id; //xyz
  var context = {
    cost: 500,
    revenue: 1000, 
  }

  res.render('../views/reports', context)
}
```

Comment: What does the id property do?

Comment: It contains the value `xyz`, sent in the request body.